# Lib Gdx what is the error and how to solve it?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, apk, bundle

When I create a bundle, I get this error.
When I create an apk or run directly from Android Studio, there are no errors.

```
# Type of exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
\n# Exception message: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.f
\n# Thread name: GLThread 467
\n# Stacktrace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.f
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.utils.e0.(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.utils.d0.c(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.utils.d0.b(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.utils.d0.d(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.e.c(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.e.b(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.d.q(Unknown Source)
\n\tat com.coulwheel.typical.i.i(Unknown Source)
\n\tat c.b.a.y.a.o.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source)
\n\tat android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
\n\tat android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
\n
```

Comment: Looks like R8 minimization has stripped away a constructor that's needed. Make sure you have the proper Proguard rules in place in your project. These are the latest provided in new libGDX projects: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-setup/res/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/resources/android/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: As I understand it, Proguard is to blame for this?

Comment: ProGuard was superseded by R8, but basically yes. R8 configuration files follow the same format as ProGuard and still use the ProGuard name by default. Code minification strips away methods and constructors it thinks you’re not using, but there can be cases where it misses a usage by reflection.

Comment: Maybe I should just disable Proguard then and not worry?

Comment: That will work but your app size will be very bloated which you might not want if putting it on the store.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Current proguard rule which is shipped with libgdx project is not fixing issue. In my project using skin.json file to create different ui object. Earlier my project was working. After updating to latest compile and target sdk to 33 and buildtools to 34.0.0, I start getting exception.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan, I’m a year behind on updating libraries so I’m not sure of the issue. You might try going on the libgdx Discord to see if others had the same issue. They are very helpful there.